# Is there a way to find specific values in a table and make it a df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file which looks like this. I want to read it and take the dataframe1 with data1 in a df and dataframe2 with data2 in another df. The location of these data can be random. Is there a way to find it and make it a df?
the tables does not exist in the same position always but the headers are always consistent.

[image: this is what my file looks like]

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx',data_only=True)
ws = wb.active
df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'data1':
            print('found')
            
            df = pd.read_excel('test123.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=cell.row, nrows=2, usecols=range(cell.col-1,cell.col+3))
            print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that should work. data_range arg should be a range much larger than where the data is located.

```
import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_interval


class ExcelDataFinder:
    """
        param: data_range: str
        param: search_for: list or str
        return: list or pd.DataFrame
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        path = "/Users/joeblow/Documents/test.xlsx"
        self.work_book = load_workbook(filename=path, read_only=True, data_only=True)
        self.data_range = kwargs.get("data_range")
        self.search_for = kwargs.get("search_for")

    def main(self) -> pd.DataFrame or list:
        return self.find_data_from_list() if isinstance(self.search_for, list) else self.find_data_from_string()

    def load_workbook_range(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        col_start, col_end = re.findall("[A-Z]+", self.data_range)
        data_rows = [[x.value for x in row] for row in self.work_book.active[self.data_range]]

        return pd.DataFrame(data_rows, columns=get_column_interval(col_start, col_end))

    def find_data_from_string(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df = self.load_workbook_range().fillna(np.nan)
        df = df[np.where(df.eq(self.search_for))[0][0]:]
        df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)

        try:
            return df.drop(columns=np.nan).dropna(how="all", axis=0).dropna(how="all", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
        except KeyError:
            pass

        return df

    def find_data_from_list(self) -> list:
        dfs = []
        for value in self.search_for:
            df = self.load_workbook_range().fillna(np.nan)
            df = df[np.where(df.eq(value))[0][0]:]
            df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)

            try:
                df = df.drop(columns=np.nan).dropna(how="all", axis=0).dropna(how="all", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
            except KeyError:
                pass

            dfs.append(df)

        return dfs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df1, df2 = ExcelDataFinder(data_range="A1:Z5000", search_for=["dataframe1", "dataframe2"]).main()
    print(f"{df1}\n")
    print(df2)

  dataframe1 data1
0       A610   656
1       B655   353
2       C698   876

  dataframe2 data2
0       A611   654
1       B646   454
2       C694   796
```